# What could be the best SQL query for this

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a table named **expense**
And it has columns named id, item, amount, date and category

So i inserted values in these fields as per my requirement
And actual values for category and amount column are:

```
Category      Amount

 bill          10
 bill          30
 entertainment 50
 health        5
 bill          60
```

And now i want to fetch category along with the amount
So for category i used

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM expense WHERE amount>0 ORDER BY category
```

In result i am getting

- bill
- entertainment
- health

And for amount i am using

```
SELECT * FROM expense WHERE amount>0 ORDER BY category
```

Output :

- 10
- 30
- 60
- 50
- 5

But i want the result for amount as :

- 100   *because total of bill is (10 + 30 + 60)
- 50
- 5

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`.

Comment: hey @GordonLinoff actually i am not very good at this so can you please write the full querry

Answer (score 3):

You want to sum up the amount values per each category-group, right?

Try:

```
select category, sum(amount) 
from expense
where amount > 0
group by category
```

If amount is never below 0, you could omit the `where amount > 0`-part.